# How to use equation of motion like this here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, vectors

So I will explain my problem exactly what it is.Please do answer in such a format by telling me places where I am wrong from the text I write.I posted this question earlier also but I noticed many of them to give answers which I didn’t even ask and had to explain all the things again in the comments. In the end , some of them leave in between or some don’t even tell the reason why the post is not good.So please check upon these points.

Questions is as follows:

Q :
particle of mass 1 kg has a velocity of 2 m/s. A constant force of 2 N acts on the particle for 1 s in a direction perpendicular to its initial velocity. Find the velocity and displacement of the particle at the end of 1 second.

My questions:

[image]

Doubt regarding direction of force:

Force means push or pull.

In image 1,

I drew the force in downwards direction or pulling force (downward vector) which is perpendicular to u (right direction)

Image 2

I drew the force in upwards direction or pushing force (upward vector) which is perpendicular to u (right direction).

So which of these 2 images is right ? Question doesn’t specify it. Also, whether what I though is right or not?

Doubt 2::

In the solution, they have made the equations of motion into two mutually perpendicular vectors.

[image]

[image]

So I thought of it for a while and thought that maybe because v is velocity, a is acceleration.So they are vectors and have a direction and can be drawn like this.

Q1 I am sure you must have had noticed the direction of vector which is in upward direction.So is it necessary for it to be in upward direction or it can be in downward direction as well.

Q2 why is t also drawn along with those vectors since time is a scalar quantity.

Q3 v = u + at in this equation. They have written v as 2$\sqrt{2}$m/s (Used by solving it in the vectors method )but if you use the equation directly. Then you get v = 2+2(1) = 4m/s.

Why are both of them different.

Q4 why did we consider direction of vector v in a direction i.e in between of u and at. Since force was supposed to there at $” at “$. It looks as if at^2 is equivalent to F = ma in the diagram. Why did that happen ?

Ok.So I am not saying that you exactly answer to me one by one. But in such a way that you cover all my doubts and not that just leave one line and don’t even respond after that.

Do tell me the exact line form the text that you didn’t understand.

Comment: Images that contain formulas aren't really welcome here because search engines can't 'read' them.

Comment: @Gert  that’s why I typed them as well.Just to show the exact text I posted that image.I also wrote the text again

Comment: @Gert In the textbook image,  they have written tan alpha = mod of at / mod of u. Is writing mod necessary ?

Comment: Taking the modulus is necessary because we're using **scalars** of vectors.

Comment: Even if a is in negative , then also ?

Comment: Scalar can have negative magnitude as well right @Gert sir

Comment: Yes, we're looking for positive values.

Comment: @Gert  ok.I wrote why not negative values if they can be possible. Like retardation case with acc = -2. What is the reason ?

Comment: Truth is, you can use neg. values if you so wish. That could lead to to negative angles but that's OK. Your textbook is basically trying to keep things simple though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Force means push or pull.

Doesn't matter.

> So which of these 2 images is right ? Question doesn’t specify it. Also, whether what I though is right or not?

It doesn't matter. When the question says *velocity* they mean the magnitude only in this case (we can see that from the wording). Sure, the direction of the force will determine wether the new velocity vector tilts one way or the other - but in both scenarios the magnitude will be the same. So it doesn't matter from which direction the force pushes, as long as it is perpendicular.

> Q1 I am sure you must have had noticed the direction of vector which is in upward direction.So is it necessary for it to be in upward direction or it can be in downward direction as well.

Again, it doesn't matter. The direction doesn't matter at all - that just depends on from where you are looking at the scenario - only the *relative* direction matters. And that is already fixed with the force being always perpendicular to initial velocity.

> Q2 why is t also drawn along with those vectors since time is a scalar quantity.

There is no rule against including scalars in vector equations. If I multiply the scalar $2$ with the vector $(1,3)$ then I get a new vector $2\cdot (1,3)=(2,6)$. No problem doing this.

> Q3 v = u + at in this equation. They have written v as $\sqrt 2$m/s (Used by solving it in the vectors method )but if you use the equation directly. Then you get v = 2+2(1) = 4m/s.

No, they have not written $v$ as $\sqrt 2$ m/s. They have written $|v|$ as $\sqrt 2$ m/s. Be careful with what is a vector ($v$) and what is a vector's magnitude ($|v|$).

If you look only in the perpendicular direction, then your equation is correct, though. Just remember to input the values that apply to this perpendicular direction also. The perpendicular acceleration $a$ comes from the force, and that acceleration can be calculated to be $F=ma\Leftrightarrow a=F/m=2\,\mathrm N\,/\,1\,\mathrm{kg}=2\,\mathrm{m/s^2}$. Using this acceleration value with your motion equation in the perpendicular direciton we get:

$$v_\perp = u_{\perp} + at=0+2\,\mathrm{m/s^2}\cdot1\,\mathrm s=2\,\mathrm{m/s}$$

So, here we have the speed component that is added to the motion in the *perpendicular direction*. The acceleration does *not* act *along with* the motion (in the direction of the initial speed) so there is *no* change along that parallel direction. In that direction the speed stays constant $$v_\parallel=u_\parallel+\underbrace{a}_0t=2\,\mathrm{m/s}+0\cdot 2\,\mathrm{s}=2\,\mathrm{m/s}$$ So, your equation v = 2+2(1) = 4m/s is not correct. With the perpendicular and the parallel components we can now find the magnitude via Pythagora's Theorem:

$$|v|^2=v_\perp^2+v_\parallel^2\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad\\ |v|=\sqrt{v_\perp^2+v_\parallel^2}=\sqrt{(2\,\mathrm{m/s})^2+(2\,\mathrm{m/s})^2}=\sqrt{8\,(\mathrm{m/s})^2}=\sqrt{8}\,\mathrm{m/s}=2\sqrt 2\,\mathrm{m/s}$$

> Q4 why did we consider direction of vector v in a direction i.e in between of u and at.

Because it *has* a direction. The motion started with only a speed component in one direction (the initial direction), $u=(u_\parallel,0)$, but ends out with a speed component in both that and now also in the perpendicular direction, $v=(v_\parallel,v_\perp)$. This is a new vector that has been tilted a bit. It has an angle.

> Since force was supposed to there at ”at“. It looks as if at^2 is equivalent to F = ma in the diagram. Why did that happen ?

Not understood. Please clarify this part.

Comment: For the last part.You see actually questions means is Force perpendicular to initial velocity.Right.Bit we used equations of motion and i noticed was all equation with acceleration in them. Like $at^2$ in S formula . Then v = u +at. Then also at is perpendicular. Not F/m. Why is that

Comment: Amazing answer you wrote.Thank you

Comment: It’s like. I didn’t understood how can you just separate a equation and as you want, you draw the perpendicular to each. u with at. ut with 1/2at^2.

Comment: So “at” meant was acceleration * time

Comment: @user102532 There are several motion equations. Typically four different ones. Two of them are:$$v=v_0+at\\s=s_0+v_0t+\frac12at^2$$Here I've written $v_0$ as initial speed, but you can also use $u$ as in your case. These are the two useful equations for your case, it seems. In both of these the $a$ is acceleration and $t$ is time, yes. Now, we actually don't have the acceleration $a$ in the given question, but luckily we can calculate it with Newton's second law $\sum F=ma$. Then we have the $a$ for the other equations.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.I have understood all , just not the last part.

Comment: If you check my 2nd image.You will notice 3 diagrams.

Comment: I am not getting how,why to draw those 3 diagram in that way.

Comment: @user102532 Diagram (a) shows the final velocity vector. On the y axis is the perpendicular speed (see my calculation; the perpendicular speed is equal to $at$, since $u_\perp=0$) and in the x axis the parallel speed (which stays the same, namely $u$, the entire time).

Comment: @user102532 Diagram (b) is final position graph. The axes are the same as before, this time just for position. See the equation in my previous comment: in the perpendicular direction (y axis) we have a squared term from the motion equation. That term disappears in the parallel direction since the acceleration is zero in that direction.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Sir , is there a way I can find 2 root 2 answer directly.Without solving it in form of components ?

Comment: @user102532 You need to know the vector (it's vector coordinates) in order to finds its magnitude. And those coordinates *are* the components. I'm not sure exactly what you mean - what does "finding it directly" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Galilean invariance tells us the motions in $x$ and $y$ directions are independent of each other.

In the $x$ direction motion is uniform, so velocity $v_x$ is constant. The displacement is:

$$\Delta x=v_x\Delta t$$

In the $y$ direction there is acceleration, so:

$$v_y=a_y\Delta t$$

The $y$ displacement is:

$$\Delta y=\frac12 a_y(\Delta t)^2$$

With $\text{N2L}$:

$$F_y=ma_y$$

$$a_y=\frac{F_y}{m}$$

Using Pythagoras, total velocity:

$$v^2=v_x^2+v_y^2$$

and total displacement:

$$(\Delta s)^2=(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2$$

Comment: Is it that I cannot write this equation for $F_x$ = m$a_x$? Since there is no acc along x axis,

Comment: Thanks gert.You solved my doubt in last question.

Comment: Also , write delta x . Just write x right

Comment: A symbol is a symbol is a symbol. If I called it 'chumbawumbah' it would be still be  OK!

Comment: Delta x is difference between two positions displacement . But x is just displacement

Comment: $\Delta x$ is the CHANGE in position, i.e. the displacement. Call it '$Xy4z$' if you prefer.